# selector query not giving any out put through java program

Tags: java, cloudant

I have written below code in java to get my stored feed from cludantDB using cloudantClinet API.

```
public List<TweetsFeed> getTweetFeed() {
        List<TweetsFeed> tweetList=new ArrayList<TweetsFeed>();
        //TweetsFeed tweetsFeed=new TweetsFeed();
        String selector="{\"selector\": {\"ANALYSIS_STATUS\" : \"N\"},\"fields\": [\"_id\",\"TWEETS_FEED\"],\"limit\": 10,\"skip\": 0 }";
        //String selector="\"selector\": {\"ANALYSIS_STATUS\" : \"N\"}";
        try{
            db = CloudantClientMgr.getDB();
            /*FindByIndexOptions options = new FindByIndexOptions()
            .fields("_id")
            .fields("SOCIALKEY")
            .fields("SCREEN_USER")
            .fields("LOCATION")
            .fields("CREATEDATE")
            .fields("TWEETS_FEED")
            .limit(10)
            .skip(0);*/
            tweetList=db.findByIndex(selector,TweetsFeed.class);
            for(int i=0;i<tweetList.size();i++){
                System.out.println("ID---->"+tweetList.get(i).getId());
                System.out.println("Text Feed--->"+tweetList.get(i).getTweetsFeed());
                System.out.println("anaStatus--->"+tweetList.get(i).getAnalysisStatus());

            }
            System.out.println("size==>"+tweetList.size());
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return tweetList;
    }
```

The **selctor** query giving out put correctly in **CloudantDB** console but through java it is not providing expected result.
I tried both was using **FindByIndexOptions** & without using **FindByIndexOptions**. In both cases code execute but showing null result.
Please tell me what is a problem in code.

Comment: What version of the Cloudant Client are you using?  What result were you expecting? When you say null result do you mean the list returned is `null` or is it empty?

Comment: tweetList.size is not null . It contains TweetsFeed objects & these object's attribute value is null.  I am using cloudant-client-2.2.0.jar.